# How to find all non zero mapping values?

Tags: solidity, storage, mapping

This question is tightly related to how mappings are stored in the storage. Is there a way to search the storage and find all non-zero values of the mapping?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mappings can only be stored [in storage](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/latest/types.html#mapping-types) and not in memory, since their maximum size is not defined. The Solidity documentation contains a detailed section on the rules for storing mappings [in storage](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.7/internals/layout_in_storage.html?highlight=layout%20in%20storage#mappings-and-dynamic-arrays). As you can read in the documentation, the storage location depends on the hash of the input values, and hereby it would be impossible to brute force all values (the range of possible values is `2^256`).

I would recommend a different approach. The mapping must have been populated with user input. You should be able to identify the `key` of each mapping entry based on the events emitted. You can then construct the storage slot by using the rules above.